# How to configure KeyboardProc to avoid keystrokes?

Tags: hook

I need to implement a code that identifies and ignores some keyboard inputs in Windows and for that I'm using that whole thing of installing a hook (I need that to block <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Windows+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Windows+D</kbd>, etc.). Given the fact that this will happen only when my software has the focus (in will be in FullScreen mode), there is no need (I think) of implementing a system-wide hook (using DLLs, etc.) and so I'm now trying to configure my `KeyboardProc` function to do what I need.

The problem is that I'm unable to make it work. I was able already to detect a specific key, but not to make Windows ignore it.

Here is what I have now (in Qt):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);

    switch(wParam)
    {
    case VK_LWIN:
        qDebug() << "VK_LWIN";
        return NULL;
    break;

    case 0x41:    //A
        qDebug() << "A";
        return false;
    break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Doesn't matter what I put in the return, the system still get the key input.

So what do I need to put there?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it after all. The difference is that I moved to use a low-level keyboard hook, so the name of the function changed. Here it is:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (nCode < 0)
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *str = (tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

switch(str->flags)
{
    case (LLKHF_ALTDOWN):
        qDebug() << "ALT";
        delete str;
    return 1;
}

if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch (str->vkCode)
    {
        case VK_RWIN:
        case VK_LWIN:
        case VK_LCONTROL:
        case VK_RCONTROL:
        case VK_APPS:
        case VK_SLEEP:
        case VK_MENU:
            qDebug() << "SPECIAL PRESS";
            delete str;
        return 1;
    }
}

return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```